# using Db2PhpEntity class (of DB2php) (or similar) is it possible to get content from DB into the class?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

The Db2PhpEntity class offers function to insert, delete, update tables using content in the class. I have several scenarios where the data is (can be) already in the database and giving values for UNIQUE set of keys i should get the data from table to populate my class fields. Are there any functions for this?
If not, if i write a function as given below, will it be alright?
This is a function for my class aptInfo (which has the fields that i am assigning in the function)
Block and Housenumber combination makes a row UNIQUE (i have used UNIQUE rather than making it a PK) and aptId is the PK. Owner_id and tenant_id are foreign keys
I create a aptInfo object using block and housenumber values and most of the times, the DB table should have the apartment i am talking about and hence i want to fetch rest of the apartment information from the DB table giving these values and have them in my class variables. Following is the function that i have written for that

```
public function getAllFieldsFromDB() {
            if($this->aptId == NULL)
            {
                //find if the apartment exists in the database
                $con = connectDB("NestAdmin", "nestadminpw");

                $query = "SELECT * from apt_info WHERE ((block = $this->block) AND (housenumber = $this->houseNumber))";

                if($result = $con->query($query)){

                    /* fetch associative array */
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $this->aptId = $row["apt_id"];
                        $this->ownerId = $row["owner_id"];
                        $this->aptArea = $row["$apt_area"];
                        $this->aptType = $row["$apt_type"];
                        $this->aptUsage = $row["$apt_usage"];
                        $this->tenantId = $row["$tenant_id"];
                    }

                    /* free result set */
                    $result->free();
                }
                /* close connection */
                $mysqli->close();

            }
        return $this->aptId;
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this?
Other "read" functions i am thinking that are generally required for all my classes are
- Find if a DB entry exists for a given UNIQUE parameter set

- Get Unique row values for given parameters (above example doesn't ensure only one row is returned) - SELECT query giving values for UNIQUE set
- Get array of row values for given zero or more parameters - SELECT query giving values to 0 or more parameters
- Get PK value for given UNIQUE parameter set
- Get given FK value giving UNIQUE parameter set

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

There are functions like FindByID (given primary key, finds the row), FindByExample, FindByFilter etc that gives you the row in the class object given the known values (set in the object instance) passed as parameter to the function
Really no need for writing a function mentioned in the question